# If you plant deer resistant plants with plants that deer like, will the deer resistance work?

Tags: deer

Is there a "bubble" created by plants that are deer resistant to protect deer prone plants from being attacked?

Comment: short answer, no, not unless there's 6 foot deer fence all the way round

Comment: 6ft? Sorry @Bamboo but 6 ft isn't enough. If a deer wants in, it will jump that with little problem. The only true deer barriers are double walled fences where the deer can see both fences and is unable to negotiate a jump over both of them. They'll still sometimes try and get caught between the fences.

Comment: White tailed deer can jump eight feet  for sure, that's true, but that assumes the fencing is upright see here (just for interest's sake) http://pss.uvm.edu/ppp/articles/deerfences.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Deer resistance is based on taste, not smell. You are confusing mammal pests with insect pests. If you look at the odor-based deer repellents they are super strong, and sometimes don't work.

"Deer resistant" plants are plants the deer do not prefer, but they still still eat them if it's a harsh winter and there is no other food. We've had deer eat hosta and daffodils, which are supposed to be deer resistant. 
Now thorny plants will be even more deer resistant.

The harshest time of the year is the spring before many shoots and berries are available. So that's when the deer are the hungriest.

If you value your plants, put hot pepper powder on them and replace after every rain. Mammals can taste the hot pepper juice.

But your best protection is a 6 foot high fence. But even then SOME occasional desperate/stupid deer have been known to jump those and get trapped in the garden. lol.

Comment: I completely agree with bulrush. I will add something else to try, though. I saw a video of a guy on youtube who put in stakes and ran a length of 12lb or 15lb test around his garden at chest high on a deer. He said it was light enough that they couldn't see it, but heavy enough for them to feel before it snapped. It "grabbed" their chest and freaked them out. He showed deer tracks all around the garden, but no damage in the garden. That's all he used. It would look better than deer fencing. I think it would be worth a try for you.

Comment: I have a field of grass around the yard with the largest population of deer in the area that the DNR actually has thinning hunts for. When I planted an apple tree the next morning the deer ate off the top.

Comment: Host is a preferred deer delectable on Long Island.

Answer (score 1):

I have three solutions:

- thick plants that physically keep out deer.
- Thorny plants (maybe a climbing rose)
- Enclosure (possibly with wood) or wire mesh (this could be small and enclose also a single plant).

And possibly keep some ground for them, so that they will stop where you care less.